# How to create group aliases in Gmail? (Like, all_my_contacts@gmail.com)

Tags: gmail

It's a standard practice to use different aliases in corporate email based on Gmail (like, `all@companyname.com` or `hr@companyname.com`).

Can I do anything similar in my ordinary Gmail account (which ends with `@gmail.com`)?

It is possible to create groups but I cannot find how to set aliases for those groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use contact groups. Automated bulk sending isn't likely to be added, because it would either let you spam people, or confuse legitimate users when most of their messages aren't delivered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can at the moment.  You could compose a new message and add the group name to the Bcc field.  Obviously not equivalent though.